# C++11 Threads Not Joining

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have experience with threads in Java but want to learn how to use them in C++11. I tried to make a simple threadpool, where threads are created once and can be asked to execute tasks.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#define NUM_THREADS 2

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(): m_running(false), m_hasData(false)
    {

    };
    ~Worker() {};

    void execute()
    {
        m_running = true;

        while(m_running)
        {
            if(m_hasData)
            {
                m_system();
            }
            m_hasData = false;
        }
    };

    void stop()
    {
        m_running = false;
    };

    void setSystem(const std::function<void()>& system)
    {
        m_system = system;
        m_hasData = true;
    };

    bool isIdle() const
    {
        return !m_hasData;
    };
private:
    bool m_running;
    std::function<void()> m_system;
    bool m_hasData;
};

class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ThreadPool()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            m_threads[i] = std::thread(&Worker::execute, &m_workers[i]);
        }
    };
    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "Stopping " << i << std::endl;
            m_workers[i].stop();
            m_threads[i].join();
        }
    };

    void execute(const std::function<void()>& system)
    {
        // Finds the first non-idle worker - not really great but just for testing
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            if(m_workers[i].isIdle())
            {
                m_workers[i].setSystem(system);
                return;
            }
        }
    };
private:
    Worker m_workers[NUM_THREADS];
    std::thread m_threads[NUM_THREADS];
};

void print(void* in, void* out)
{
    char** in_c = (char**)in;
    printf("%s\n", *in_c);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ThreadPool pool;
    const char* test_c = "hello_world";
    pool.execute([&]() { print(&test_c, nullptr); });
}
```

The output of this is:

```
hello_world
Stopping 0
```

After that, the main thread halts, because it's waiting for the first thread to join (in the destructor of the ThreadPool). For some reason, the `m_running` variable of the workers is not set to false, which keeps the application running indefinitely.

Comment: it works fine on my PC. built with visual studio 2013

Comment: @DavidHaim: The code contains undefined behaviour. It is perfectly possible that the code behaves as expected. Howerver because access to the shared variable m_running is not synchronized the compiler can assume that it will not change in the worker thread. Even if the compiler does not optimize it away, the CPU can assume the same and never update the cache entry for m_running with the changed value from another CPU or core. So the resulting behaviour depends on your compiler, its optimizations and your CPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Worker::stop` the member `m_running` is written in the main thread, while it is read in execute in a different thread. This is undefined behavior. You need to protect read/write access from different threads. In this case I would recommend using `std::atomic<bool>` for `m_running`.

Edit: the same holds for `m_hasData`.

Comment: +1. Just to add why this is necessary is explained in https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Comment: Will I have to do this for *everything* that is created/read/written in one thread and executed in another? If I add tasks to the thread pool, these tasks need to be atomic or use a mutex too?